# What type of property work on VisualState.Setters (Targeting different devices from a Universal Windows App)

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app, visualstatemanager, windows-10-mobile

I have problem, I create my own Usercontrol and I create some property and use the original property such as FontSize property and so on.

When I want to use this property for targeting different devices from a Universal Windows App via Blend I've got errors and I can't gain access to original property to set VisualState.Setters.

This error message when i set value for visualstate :
**the property value is not valid**

I you don't understand you can see my codes :

```
private int _fontSize;
    /// <summary>
    /// Set font size for text caption
    /// </summary>
    public new int FontSize
    {
        get { return _fontSize; }
        set
        {
            _fontSize = value;
            TxtCaption.FontSize = _fontSize;
        }
    }
```

this code is one of my property I use for set font size to my textblock object.

when I want to set font size when windows 10 app size change automatically textblock font size change but I,ve got error and I can't set to my own property

```
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroupDevices">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Phone5in">
                <VisualState.Setters>

                    <Setter Target="BtnInbox.(FrameworkElement.FlowDirection)" Value="LeftToRight"/>
                    <Setter Target="BtnInbox.(Control.FontSize)" Value="20"/>

                </VisualState.Setters>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowHeight="640" MinWindowWidth="360" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            </VisualState>

        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt210475.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt210475.aspx)

this code never set on XAML

```
<Setter Target="BtnInbox.(Control.FontSize)" Value="20"/>
```

please help me what type of property I have to use to work.

thanks by
Hussein Habibi Juybari

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you have this problem because your property is not a dependency property.

Comment: thanks for you answer. at first I think about use dependency property, after create property I mean original property or my property it didn't work and I got error again. I use dependency property and it didn't work